# Why is the battery discharging fast when Charging On Hold

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, apple-silicon

So, I got a new MBP M1 in March. I guess it took about 3-4 months for the OS to learn my battery charging pattern. So, now pretty much every morning when I open the laptop, it's in state `Charging On Hold (Rarely Used On Battery)`. Which makes sense, because 99% of the time the laptop is on my desk, connected to the screen and charging.

Now, the issue is that when it's in this state, the actual battery discharges *very fast*. I'm talking about 1% per few minutes. Which is not normal... when I use the laptop on a battery it doesn't discharge so fast.

Does someone know why this quick discharge is happening? Is it bad? Should I just let it be?

[image]